# Why would rmdir /s fail but still delete the innermost subdirectory?

Tags: windows, cygwin

I had a directory structure (src/...) created by Cygwin's 7za.exe.  From a command prompt I ran `rmdir /s /q src`.

This resulted in error messages (paraphrasing as my DOS shell has long since overflowed):

> Cannot delete src/test/unit/geom
>
> The directory is not empty

Browsing to `src/test/unit/geom` showed that it was indeed empty, so I ran the same rmdir command again.  Same error, but pointing at `src/test/unit` instead.  And my Explorer window that was showing the absence of contents in `src/test/unit/geom` dropped down to `src/test/unit`.

Three rmdir executions later, it is fully gone.

This is Windows 7 and `set CYGWIN=nontsec` had been run.  I believe this has been the source of [build problems](https://superuser.com/q/350405/89858) for some time now, but until now I hadn't identified the culprit.

What can I do to avoid this in the future?  If it happens again, what should I look for in terms of identifying corrupt aspects of the directory structure?

Comment: What command interpreter was running as this "command prompt"?  Microsoft's CMD?  bash?  TCC?  [It's not a "DOS shell", by the way.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/a-cli-is-not-a-dos-prompt.html)  DOS has nothing to do with it; and you aren't running DOS.

Comment: @JdeBP DOS shell on Windows 7 == CMD

Comment: No, that's not a DOS shell.  It's a Win32 program.  DOS has nothing to do with it, as I said.  Moreover: I _already know_ what comes in the box.  That's not the question that you were asked.  But I also know that you're the sort of person who installs things like Cygwin.  So for the second time: _What command interpreter were you using?_

Comment: I am mystified. I tried this and it didn't work, then I tried the exact same command and it did work. Buggy? Circumstances unknown mitigating the behavior? First, it only removed a whole subdirectory tree provided all the directories are empty (apart from having subfolders--) in other words it did not work when files were in the folder. Then it did work with files in the folder. ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can reproduce the problem, try using [Sysinternals ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) (or FileMon) to see what's happening under the covers.  It's been a while since I've look at this stuff but IIRC, cygwin performs some fancy steps to replicate Unix semantics and the results are not always perfect.

Comment: No repro since I started looking hard at the issue, but if I ever get one I'm confident ProcMon will be the answer.